# How do I manually add an additional participant to an event?

Tags: civievent

In using the 'back end' to register people for an event /civicrm/participant/add?reset=1&action=add&context=standalone.

I'm getting a message stating that *email address* is already registered for the event. The event allows for up to 6 additional participants.

Answer (score 1):

A person is not allowed to register for same event twice with same email address. However this can be bypassed by enabling '**Same email address?**' option under '**Online Registration**' tab of an event.

[image]

Comment: It is already checked. Version 4.7.25 if I didn't say that.

Comment: Are you using front end or back end form to register?

Comment: Front end works fine - back end 'manually add' does not.